# Sample from multivariate normal distribution with given positive-semidefinite covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I want to draw a random vector from a multivariate normal distribution with given covariance matrix $Σ$.

I'm following [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) algorithm:

> A widely used method for drawing a random vector $x$ from the $N$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution with mean vector $μ$ and covariance matrix $Σ$ works as follows:
>
> 1. Find any real matrix $A$ such that $AA^T = Σ$. When $Σ$ is positive-definite (...)

But my covariance matrix is not positive-definite. It's positive-semidefinite. So, I can't use Cholesky decomposition. Further there is written:

> An alternative is to use the matrix $A = UΛ^{\frac{1}{2}}$ obtained from a spectral decomposition $Σ = UΛU^T$ of $Σ$.

So, I have to use spectral decomposition? There is no easier way to draw such a random vector?

---

For such $Σ$:

```
 0.666 -0.333
-0.333  0.666
```

**Cholesky decompososition** gives such $A$ (using this [Online Matrix Calculator](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/)):

```
 0.816  0.000
-0.408  0.707
```

**Spectral decomposition**, eigenvectors real values $U$:

```
 0.707  0.707
-0.707  0.707
```

Eigenvalues $Λ$:

```
 0.999  0.000
 0.000  0.333
```

Fortunately square root of diagonal matrix is easy :) $Λ^{\frac{1}{2}}$:

```
 0.999  0.000
 0.000  0.577
```

$A=UΛ^{\frac{1}{2}}$:

```
 0.707  0.407
-0.707 0.407
```

So, $A$ returned by spectral decomposition is different than this returned by Cholesky. Why? Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both seem to work quite well. They give slightly different results for the estimated covariance matrices of the generated series, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's due to rounding errors somewhere in the computations.

Below is some R code which generates samples from $N(0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$.

```
n <- 10000000

X <- cbind(rnorm(n), rnorm(n))

sigma <- t(matrix(c(0.666, -0.333, -0.333, 0.666), nrow=2))
spectral <- eigen(sigma)

X.spectral <- t(spectral$vectors %*% sqrt(diag(spectral$values)) %*% t(X))
X.cholesky <- t(t(chol(sigma)) %*% t(X))
cov(X.spectral)
cov(X.cholesky)
```

So with my 10,000,000 samples, the covariance matrices are

```
> cov(X.spectral)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.6660626 -0.3331138
[2,] -0.3331138  0.6658130
> cov(X.cholesky)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.6660344 -0.3328923
[2,] -0.3328923  0.6656198
```